# How to sum() query in C# using sql yog

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlyog

i am trying to get Sum() of value in my database data using C# but i am having an error Exception error sql type -0 here is my Code.

the problem is here when i am passing value through dr i am always getting exception error

[image]

ArgumentException has unhandled 
Unknown Sql type -0

Comment: What is the exception _exactly_? Why don't use use `ExecuteScalar` instaed of data reader since your query returns just one value? By the way, you try to assing `int` to `string` on `Convert.ToInt32` line which is not allowed.

Comment: maybe instead of label.text = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()); will be label.text = dr[0].ToString();

Comment: Did you check for null? If the table is empty, SUM will return NULL

Comment: @Jamaxack maybe it should be just `dr[0].ToString()`, assuming `dr` is a DataRow. There's no reason to convert to int if you want to display a string

Comment: even when i am using integer entities i encapsulated an integer then i used it to pass entities.income = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].toString());

Comment: @shampoo what is the actual exception?? It's impossible to help without knowing it. At least try to debug the code, and check the value returned by `dr[0].ToString()`. Have you even initialized `dr` or are you getting a NullReferenceException? Are you reading the correct field, or does `dr[0]` contain a string like `John Wayne`? Does the table contain any non-NULL income values or is the value of `dr[0]` null?

Comment: @shampoo see my ans. May be it will help you.

Comment: how can i paste screenshots here?

Comment: look i've editted my post argumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use linq,you can fix like this:

```
label.Text=(from f in audittrail_tbl
            select f).Sum(S=>S.Income).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ExecuteScalar`

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Sum(Income) FROM audittrail_tbl";

var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int result = obj != null ? (int)obj : 0;
connection.Close();
```

You should check for `null` before casting the value to `int`.

Comment: Won't work if the table is empty - SUM will return NULL

Comment: You can use `int result= (int)(obj??0)`. The `??` operator was added in .NET 2.0 for this scenario

Comment: in my case i am using dbfactory so i need to make 3 different methods and in every query i should only make one return value ?